# change upload path in symfony project

Tags: php, web-services, symfony

I am working on customizing a symfony project called qdPM available at qdpm.net Its open source project management system and I am trying to configure it to use within my small back office management.

I did much of the customization, but I am stuck in a much disastrous situation.

I have two hosting packages, one is with unlimited web space (A) and the other is having only 100MB of space(B). I had earlier decided to host only the project files on my server B and to keep the database of the system on server A, I did it successfully. However, there is one more factor that is troubling me. My upload files are going to the ../uploads/attachments/ directory on my server B.

I want them on my server A, is it possible... I am a novice in symfony and am on its journey for last two days. Please explain...